# В mysql workbench не могу найти my.ini

Tags: mysql

Всем добрый день. В mysql workbench (8) указан путь к файлу my.ini, хотя самого файла в фолдере нет. Он где-то в другом месте хранится, или его вовсе нет? Как его найти/создать?

Comment: *В mysql workbench (8) указан путь к файлу my.ini* Эммм... где? my.ini - файл настроек MySQL-СЕРВЕРА. У него и нужно искать...

Comment: Т.е.? Вот в воркбенч у меня прописан путь к конфиг. файлу (%ProgramFiles%\...\my.ini), а в этом местоположении его не существует (хотя через поисковик "компьютера" нашёл). На самом деле, не очень понял, о чём вы

Comment: Вы явно что-то не то говорите. У воркбенча никакого my.ini нет в принципе. А "путь к конфиг-файлу" - это путь к конфигу инстанса MySQL в настройках соединения с сервером. Клиентское настройки берутся именно оттуда. Соответственно этот файл к самому воркбенчу никакого отношения не имеет.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за пояснение